# Should I add the "www/lib" folder in an Ionic project to Git?

Tags: git, ionic-framework, bower, dependency-management

Or any SCM?  We're using Bower to manage our dependencies and this folder is created with all the dependencies by `bower install`.  Does it make sense to add that to my `.gitignore` and run `bower install` when the project is checked out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense to ignore the dependencies and load them using bower after the project is checked out. You don't need to version control your dependencies as those are already under version control. They would just blow up your repository.

Comment: This is what I did.